# One-loop Integral for a Tensor Quantity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, integration, regularization

I am considering one-loop integrals in quantum field theory.  I am happy with how these calculations work with scalar integrals, but I am a bit lost in the details of what happens when the quantity inside the integral is a tensor.  As an example, consider
$$\int \frac{d^d k}{( 2 \pi)^d} \frac{g_{\mu \nu} + \frac{k_{\mu} k_{\nu}}{M^2}}{k^2 + M^2}.$$
In simple terms, how is this integral evaluated?

For the moment I am not interested in the general case of multi-loop integrals as this will be even more complicated.

Comment: You could always start by looking at Passarino-Veltman reduction. By the way no need to overcomplicate your first tensor integral, you could have just started with $k^{\mu}k^{\nu}$ in the numerator.

Comment: I saw this mentioned, is it best to learn this in the original paper or is there pedagogical material where it is explained which you recommend?

Comment: Honestly I have personally cobbled together my understanding of Pa-Ve reduction from various sources based on how easily read they were. I don't have any suggestions offhand unfortunately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define the tensor,
$$
A_{\mu\nu} = \int \frac{d^dk}{(2\pi)^d}  \frac{ \eta_{\mu\nu} + \frac{k_\mu k_\nu }{M^2 } }{ k^2 + M^2 - i \epsilon } 
$$
The important thing to note is that this tensor is Lorentz invariant. To see this, we note
$$
A_{\alpha\beta} \Lambda^\alpha{}_\mu \Lambda^\beta{}_\nu = \int \frac{d^dk}{(2\pi)^d}  \frac{ \eta_{\alpha\beta} \Lambda^\alpha{}_\mu \Lambda^\beta{}_\nu + \frac{ ( k_\alpha \Lambda^\alpha{}_\mu ) ( k_\beta \Lambda^\beta{}_\nu  ) }{M^2 } }{ k^2 + M^2 - i \epsilon } 
$$
We can now change integration variable $k_\mu \to k_\nu (\Lambda^{-1} )^\nu{}_\mu$. $k^2$ is Lorentz invariant and so is the measure $d^d k$. Further $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is Lorentz invariant so we have
$$
A_{\alpha\beta} \Lambda^\alpha{}_\mu \Lambda^\beta{}_\nu  = A_{\mu\nu} . 
$$
This implies that $A_{\mu\nu}$ is a Lorentz invariant tensor!

However, there are only two Lorentz invariant tensors, the metric (by definition) $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ and the volume form $\epsilon_{\mu_1 \cdots \mu_d}$. Consequently, $A_{\mu\nu}$ must depend only on these two tensors. Since it has two indices, the only possible form for this tensor is
$$
A_{\mu\nu} = A \eta_{\mu\nu} = \int \frac{d^dk}{(2\pi)^d}  \frac{ \eta_{\mu\nu} + \frac{k_\mu k_\nu }{M^2 } }{ k^2 + M^2 - i \epsilon }  . 
$$
To find $A$, we contract both sides with $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ and find
$$
A = \int \frac{d^dk}{(2\pi)^d}  \frac{ 1  + \frac{ k^2}{ d M^2 } }{ k^2 + M^2 - i \epsilon }  . 
$$

We have now managed to simplify our "tensor integral" to a scalar one. This can now be evaluated in the usual way.

Answer (score 4):

The [accepted answer by Prahar](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/776787/70245) covers what you need to do in many cases that arise in particle physics contexts, but there are situations in which is not sufficiently general.  The key idea is correct, that you identify the Lorentz structure than can be present in the final answer and then contract the integrand with something to reduce the the integral to a scalar that can be evaluated in the usual fashion.  However, sometimes there may be more than one allowed tensor structure, so the integral will need to be contracted with different things and the the resulting integrals evaluated.  (The specific integral in the question is particularly simple because it does not depend on any quantity—such as an exchanged four-momentum—with Lorentz indices.)

As an example, let me point to the calculation in this paper of mine:  [*Physical Review D*, **70** 101701 (2004)](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.70.101701) ([arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0407172)). I had the problem of calculating a radiative correction to the photon self-energy with this form
$$\Pi^{\mu\nu}=ie^{2}\int\frac{d^{4}k}{(2\pi)^{4}}\frac{1}{\left(k^{2}-m^{2}\right)^{4}}\,{\rm tr}\left\{\gamma^{\mu}(\!\not k+m)\!\not\! b\,(\!\not k-m)\gamma^{\nu}(\!\not k-m)\!\not\! b\,(\!\not k+m)\right.\\
+\left.\left[\gamma^{\mu}(\!\not k+m)\gamma^{\nu}(\!\not k+m)\!\not\! b\,(\!\not k
-m)\!\not\!b\, (\!\not k+m)+(\mu\leftrightarrow\nu)\right]\right\},$$
which depended on an external vector $b^{\mu}$.  In this case $b^{\mu}$ was an exotic background vector, but this situation could arise equally easily with some other quantity, such as external momentum $p^{\mu}$.  In this case, there are two possible two-index symmetric tensor structures that might appear in the integrated expression for $\Pi^{\mu\nu}$; both $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ and $b^{\mu}b^{\nu}$ are possible.

Therefore, I wrote the general form of $\Pi^{\mu\nu}$ as
$$\Pi^{\mu\nu}=A(b^{2})b^{\mu}b^{\nu}+B(b^{2})\eta^{\mu\nu}b^{2};$$
since there are two unknown functions $A$ and $B$, two separate integrals need to be evaluated.  Contracting with $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ produces one scalar integral,
$$\eta_{\mu\nu}\Pi^{\mu\nu}=4ie^{2}\int\frac{d^{4}k}{(2\pi)^{4}}
\frac{16m^{2}[2(b\cdot k)^{2}-b^{2}k^{2}]-10m^{4}b^{2}}
{\left(k^{2}-m^{2}\right)^{4}}= -\frac{e^{2}b^{2}}{4\pi^{2}}$$
(ultraviolet finite, in spite of the apparent logarithmic divergence).
The gives one relation for $A$ and $B$,
$$Ab^{2}+4Bb^{2}=-\frac{e^{2}b^{2}}{4\pi^{2}},$$
and the other comes from calculating another contraction,
$$\frac{b_{\mu}b_{\nu}}{b^{2}}\Pi^{\mu\nu}=(A+B)b^{2}=-\frac{e^{2}b^{2}}{8\pi^{2}}.$$
The problem is final reduced to solving the linear equations for $A$ and $B$, with the final result
$$\Pi^{\mu\nu}= -\frac{e^{2}}{24\pi^{2}}\left(2b^{\mu}b^{\nu}+
\eta^{\mu\nu}b^{2}\right).$$

More elaborate Lorentz structures are also possible, when there are dependences on additional external quantities.  In another paper, [G. Bonneau, L. C. Costa, and J. L. Tomazelli, *International Journal of Theoretical Physics* **47**, 1764 (2008)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10773-007-9619-4) ([arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0510045)), for the calculation of a different contribution to the photon self-energy in the same theory, the authors needed to account for four possible Lorentz structures.  Each of them may be projected out by contraction with the right kind of tensor, yielding four integrals to be performed.  Fortunately, this is actually not as much work as it may sound like.  The contractions only affect the numerators of the integrals; the denominators are already scalars and are unaffected.  So if you combine the denominators using Feynman parameters, that only needs to be done once, and it can be done before the contractions, meaning that however many explicit integrals need to be evaluations, they all tend to have quite similar structures.